# Display Twitter followers of a twitter account

Tags: html, api, twitter, twitter-follow

How can I get the number of followers of any Twitter account? I want to display the number of followers of 4 different Twitter accounts in my web page, with the goal of determining who has the most followers.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? What code language are you using? If you want people to help here, you've at least got to show some research and tries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter API docs:

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show

```
GET users/show
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json
```

Comment: I am trying to get the followers list for a specific Twitter user, can you please guide me, here is the question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76726633/get-twitter-account-followers-using-api-and-google-apps-script